# Can I set driver's version when use zalenium

Tags: automation, webdriver, zalenium

I tried to use Zalenium to run my automation cases. The default driver version is latest like chromedriver is v84 but I wanna to use version 76. Is there any way to change it?
My automation is running with TestNG + selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use one of the docker images that has the versions you need, you can check the releases at `elgalu/docker-selenium` here https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/releases

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to mapping local driver and not using selenium container embedded driver?

Comment: I tried with elgalu/docker-selenium and it is working.

Comment: No, it is not possible to use a local driver. The advantage of using the images is to have an environment where things work and has been tested.